# Написать программу (Python) для поиска информации в файлах pdf

Tags: python

Уважаемое сообщество!
Передо мной задача.
Дано: архив/подборка журналов в формате *.pdf в папках сортированных по годам. Например: журнала номер 1 за первый месяц 2010 года в папке 2010. Общий размер всей подборки по годам 13Гиг.
Надо написать программу на Python чтобы по запросу пользователя шерстила журналы и на выходе предлагала список журналов в которых есть данная информация.
Python только начал изучать. Прошу указать путь в каком двигаться для решения данной задачи?
Спасибо!

Comment: для мат части читайте про индексацию поисковых систем, для python - Лутца

Comment: Вот ссылки, должно хватить      https://bdseo.ru/kak-chitat-dannye-s-pdf-cherez-python-3-pypdf2                       http://pingi-pingi.blogspot.com/2017/11/pdf-python-pdf-python-pdfminer-pdf.html                               https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/

Comment: пасибо большое буду курить

Comment: ЕМНИП и `ElasticSearch` и `Solr` умеют индексировать PDF файлы. Выберете себе один из них, проиндексируйте файлы и ищите на здоровье